# Do you know a C# implementation of Gauss Newton and Levenberg Marquardt methods?

Tags: c#, algorithm, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am looking for a C# implementation of both Gauss Newton & Levenberg Marquardt algorithms. Is there any "trustee" C# library out there already?

Comment: Sorry to say that [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/140505). Nor is it [A Link Farm or Search Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128549).

Answer (score 2):

you can take a look of this list of [numerical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries#.NET_Framework_Languages_C.23.2C_F.23_and_VB.NET) libraries